# Working out the distance between two postcodes

Tags: php, geolocation, distance, pythagorean

I have looked at other questions that have been answered however, I am still unsure on how to;

1. Get UK postcode data including Longitude, Latitude, Grid-N and Grid-E into my database
2. If I use an API how do I go about it? Where do I start from?
3. Would I need to use Pythagorus Theorem to calculate the distance between the two postcodes?
4. I have got a table in my database for when a user adds a property. Maybe, there is a way when someone adds a property, it can add that postcode along with the postcodes other information (long, lat, grid-ref) into my Postcodes table so that I can work out the distance between the two postcodes.

Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: As a hint, don't use Pythagorus Theorem, except for very close distances - you're more likely to want the Great Circle distance

Comment: Also, worth looking at [OS's OpenData](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) (which [My Society mirror](http://parlvid.mysociety.org/os/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a class I use specifically for this:

```
class Geocode
{
    /**
     * Work out the distance between two sets of lat/lng coordinates as the crow flies.
     *
     * @param float $lat1
     * @param float $lng1
     * @param float $lat2
     * @param float $lng2
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public static function distance($lat1 = 0.0, $lng1 = 0.0, $lat2 = 0.0, $lng2 = 0.0) {
        $theta = $lng1 - $lng2;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        return $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    }

    /**
     * Get the lat/lng coordinates for an address.
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return stdClass
     */
    public static function convert($address = '')
    {
        $address = str_replace(" ", "+", urlencode(str_replace(PHP_EOL, ', ', $address)));
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&region=uk&sensor=false";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);

        if($response['status'] != 'OK') {
            return (object) ['status' => $response['status']];
        }
        $geo = $response['results'][0]['geometry'];

        return (object) [
            'lat'       => $geo['location']['lat'],
            'lng'       => $geo['location']['lng'],
            'status'    => $response['status']
        ];
    }
}
```