# Using Haversine Formula to workout the distance between two postcodes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, distance, latitude-longitude

I am trying to use the Haversine Formula in php to work out the distance between two postcodes; So far I have created a function to work out the distance. My database table is called 'postcode' and the fields 'postcode_id','postcode','lat','lng'.

```
    <script>
function getDistance($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2) {  
    $earth_radius = 6371;  

    $postLat = deg2rad($latitude2 - $latitude1);  
    $postLon = deg2rad($longitude2 - $longitude1);  

    $a = sin($postLat/2) * sin($postLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * sin($postLon/2) * sin($postLon/2);  
    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));  
    $d = $earth_radius * $c;  

    return $d; 
}
</script>

<?php
$postcode_qry = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$postLat."*pi()/180)) * sin(('lat'*pi()/180))+cos((".$postLat."*pi()/180)) * cos(('lat'*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$postLon."- 'lng')*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance
FROM `postcode` WHERE distance = ".$d."");

?>
```

Comment: But there are so many examples!?!?!?!!

Comment: @Strawberry could you elaborate and maybe give me a link to one of these examples please.

Comment: Search this forum for 'haversine' or 'longitude'.  Or click on the 'latitude-longitude' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request it with the google service :

```
    function getLongLat($address) {
        $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&language=nl&address='+$address;

        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);  
        $obj = simplexml_load_string($response);
        if ($obj) {
            $obj = $obj->result;
            return array( 'latitude' => $obj->geometry->location->lat.'', 'longitude' => $obj->geometry->location->lng.'',);
        }else{
            return [];
        } 

   }
```

Google will try and parse the address for you, guessing `postal code, Country` should work for you as an address and than you can pass the required data to your `MySQL` function

Comment: It does not, but if you read the content of OP's question you see he already has the math in place but was missing the coordinates of the places he needed calculated the distance between. Hence my comment in the end of my answer...

Comment: He also [keeps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36261299/50447) [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36234233/50447) [the same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36216670/50447) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36205761/50447), even though [it was answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36205860/50447)